# Closed set and derivative

Tags: calculus

$A= \{(x, y, z) ∈ R^3 : 0 ≤ x < 1, 0 ≤ y < 1, 0 ≤ z < 1 \}.$ Is this closed or open set? My opinion is open.Also I don't know how to solve this problem:
Does $(xy)^\frac{1}{3}$ have derivative at $(0,0)$ and what about $(x+y)^\frac{1}{3}$ again at $(0,0)$?

Comment: How are open and closed sets defined? Have you heard about accumulation points?. For the second question, how have you defined a derivative when you have more than one independent variable?

Answer (score 1):

The set $A$ is neither open nor closed, because of equalities in left side and inequalities in right side.